# Reduce 3d to 2d array by using an index vector for one dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a `M x N x O` matrix and I would like to reduce it to a `MxN` matrix in MATLAB using a vector `b` of size `M` that contains the index of the element in the third dimension that is to be kept.

What it does then is build a 2d array with its entries selected from various pages of the original 3d array.

I have this loop but I am interested in a loopless solution.

```
for i = 1:M
    for j = 1:N
        tmp(i, j) = P(i, j, b(i));
    end
end
```

Comment: You could just remove the `j` loop altogether and replace `j` with `:` and it would do the same thing, right?

Comment: @beaker yes, good thinking. However do you see any way to do this completely loopless?

Comment: Yes, I can give you a way to do it with `ndgrid` and `sub2ind`. I don't know how much that will buy you, but if you're interested I can post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way may just be to remove the `j` loop in your code:

```
for ii = 1:M
    tmp(ii, :) = P(ii, :, b(ii));
end
```

But for the sake of comparison, here's a solution without a loop.

---

Given a 3d array `P`:

```
M = 7;
N = 5;
O = 6;
P = ones(M, N, O) .* permute(1:O, [3 1 2]);
```

(in this case I've used a 3d array where each element is equal to its `O` index)
and `b`, of size `Mx1` with values from `1..O`:

```
b = randi(O, M, 1)
```

you can construct the subscripts of all of the elements of `P(:,:,1)` and use `b` to select which plane to use:

```
[rr, cc] = ndgrid(1:M, 1:N);
inds = sub2ind(size(P), rr(:), cc(:), b(rr(:)));
tmp = reshape(P(inds), M, N)
```

For:

```
b.' =    5   4   1   5   3   1   3
```

we get:

```
tmp =

   5   5   5   5   5
   4   4   4   4   4
   1   1   1   1   1
   5   5   5   5   5
   3   3   3   3   3
   1   1   1   1   1
   3   3   3   3   3
```

The elements of each row corresponds to the element in `b` as expected.